# Given the four vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which combinations are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\vec{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}
         2\\-5\\4\\3\\
        \end{bmatrix}
\vec{v_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
         2\\-1\\2\\7\\
        \end{bmatrix}
\vec{v_3}=\begin{bmatrix}
         3\\-1\\4\\5\\
        \end{bmatrix}
\vec{v_4}=\begin{bmatrix}
         3\\-6\\4\\12\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
If I construct a matrix $M$ with the 4 given vectors $[\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3},\vec{v_4}]$, I can then take the determinant of the matrix.
$$
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\
    -5 & -1 & -1 & -6\\
    4 & 2 & 4 & 4\\
    3 & 7 & 5 & 12
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since $det(M) = 0$, the given vectors are linearly dependent which implies that at least one of them is a linear combination of the others. I'm not sure how to go about finding that other than to guess and check.

Comment: If $\mathrm{det}(M)$ is zero, then, for _every_ choice of $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, $v_i$ is a linear combination of the remaining three vectors. Start by solving $M\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ for $\vec{x}$.

Comment: @TeXminator that is not true.  Take for counterexample $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$  The vector first vector can *not* be written as a linear combination of the remaining vector.  What is true is that for **some** choice of $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$...

Comment: The lower left minor of order 2 is 22 so the first two vectors are independent and rank is at least 2.Try to consider any minor of order 3 including these vectors and you should be all set. And yes... this is guess and check!

Comment: @polettix it doesn't need to be guess and check.  There are methods available.  Feel free to try to prove on your own time that the method I describe below in fact works.

Comment: @JMoravitz I didn't mean that it can be solved only by guess and check... only that my approach is indeed guess and check :-)

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry for causing confusion. Of course, in a system of linearly dependent vectors, _at least one of them_ is a linear combination of the remaining ones. It is by no means clear whether _all_ vectors of the given system have this property (even if all of the vectors are non-zero). Anyway, for the OP's matrix $M$, actually _every_ column can be written as a linear combination of the remaining ones because there are solutions of the equation $M\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ with only non-zero components.

Answer (score 1):

To find what linear combinations will give a dependency, you can approach via row reduction.

Letting $M=\begin{bmatrix} \mid&\mid&\mid&\mid\\ v_1&v_2&v_3&v_4\\ \mid&\mid&\mid&\mid\end{bmatrix}$, if we row reduce, we can be told which vectors are linearly dependent (building our list from left to right).

In this case, you get $rref(M) = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&2\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

This implies that $v_4 = v_1+2v_2-v_3$

The location of the pivots as well implies that the original columns in those locations act as a basis for the span of the vectors (and are thus independent).

In general, if the $k^{th}$ column of the row reduced matrix looks like $\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\\vdots\end{bmatrix}$ then $v_k = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3+\dots$

One could also consider instead $M^T = \begin{bmatrix}- v_1^T -\\
- v_2^T-\\
-v_3^T-\\
-v_4^T-\end{bmatrix}$ and row reduce, it will give us that the resulting nonzero rows (transposed) act as a basis for the span of the set of vectors as well.