# Write each column of AB as a linear combination of the columns of A. Find AB

Tags: matrices

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 &-1&3\\ 0&4&5\\-3&0&-2\\ \end{pmatrix}$
$B=\begin{pmatrix} -1 &1&4\\ 3&2&1\\5&-3&-1\\ \end{pmatrix}$

The bit that's throwing me off here is, "write each column of $AB$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$".

I've calculated $AB$:

$$AB=\begin{pmatrix} 10&-9&4\\ 37&-7&-7\\-7&3&-10\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

How do I proceed?

Comment: Do you know how to find how to write an individual vector as a linear combination of other vectors?  How do you write $\begin{bmatrix}10\\37\\-7\end{bmatrix}$ in terms of the columns of $A$?  See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678585/given-the-four-vectors-in-mathbbr3-which-combinations-are-linearly-indepe?noredirect=1#comment3426441_1678585) and see if you can't modify the approach to take care of all at one time.

Comment: Also, you would notice that when you originally wrote your post, your matrices were unreadable as they normally are displayed.  Only by going in to the edit window could we read what you intended.  The way it appears in the edit window is not how it appears when it is displayed.  It will help make your posts cleaner and clearer if you learn how to type in MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  [Visit this page for information on how.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Similar to:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534873/matrix-multiplication-express-a-column-as-a-linear-combination

Comment: Note that element AB(2,3) should be -1 not -7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

Row reduce the augmented matrix $[A\mid AB]$

The entries of the $k^{th}$ column in the row reduced form, $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\alpha_3\\\vdots\end{bmatrix}$, implies that $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3+\dots = v_k$

---

Even simpler in this case though, is to notice that in doing so, $rref[A\mid AB] = [I\mid A^{-1}AB]=[I\mid B]$, so the right-side result of the row reduction process will simply be the matrix $B$.

The first column of $AB$ is equal to $-1 v_1+3v_2+5v_3$ for example.